# Aggregate results of top_hits with date_histogram or similar?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index containing one document for every visit event to our site in a day, which contains the time of the visit and a user ID and the same user can visit multiple times in the same day. I am trying to get the number of users visiting for the first time that day per minute. Is this possible to do in a single query?

I know that a top_hits aggregation within a terms aggregation, sorted by the time field, will get me the documents representing the first unique visit each day. I know that date_histogram will aggregate the visits by minute, but not apply a uniqueness check. A cardinality subaggregation of date_histogram only verifies uniqueness per bucket, not over the whole day. date_histogram doesn't accept pipeline specifications for what to aggregate over.

I'm currently afraid that the only answer is to do the top_hits aggregation and then aggregate it myself client side, or do a separate query for every minute I want to verify unique users over (something like query for unique user ids from midnight to 12:01 AM, then midnight to 12:02, etc, tracking the growth in the count in each query.)

Comment: Other terrible ideas I've considered - doing a terms&top_hits aggregation to get the complete set of document ids representing first unique visits, and then doing a ids query to only return those documents and doing a date_histogram on that... but that's a physically HUGE request I'd be building.

Comment: It’s hard to figure out what the question is here: please split the first long paragraph into shorter sentences and phrase the question as a question.

Comment: Not really sure how to split the first one into shorter sentences - it's one action I'd like to do in one query. Does such a query exist?

Comment: Took a stab at cleaning it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple aggregations in a single elasticsearch query it goes like 
`{
        "query": {
          // some query
        },
        "aggs": {
          "aggregation1": {
          },
          "aggrgation2": {
          },
    }`

Comment: That doesn't solve it though - I don't want the non unique visitors per minute or the unique over the whole day. I want unique visitors (relative to the day) per minute, just one set of buckets. How do I construct those?